# SQL Server stored procedure does not execute command when invoked from another server/framework but works locally

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, rollback, sql-execution-plan

I have created a SQL Server stored procedure which contains insert and update statements and log table. When I execute the stored procedure locally using

```
EXEC stored_procedure_name param1
```

it works perfectly fine and logs entry is inserted into the log table; but when the same stored procedure is called from another server using the same SQL Server user, the stored procedure is called and correct output/response is going to calling server but insert and update statements are not executed and no logs are inserted.

Again, when I call the stored procedure locally, everything works. When I checked the entries in log table (with `Id` column as `identity(1,1)`), there are 2 entries with id 1 and 3.

I think entry with Id = 2 is inserted and then rollback as it called from another server.

I don't understand the different behavior. Please help.

Thanks in advance

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[temp_procedure] 
    (@aid VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @RETURN_CODE INT = -2;
    DECLARE @RETURN_MESSAGE VARCHAR(MAX) = 'ENTITY NOT FOUND';

    -- Check IF exist and  Update
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM temp WHERE c = @aid)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE temp
        SET a = 0, b = 0,               
        WHERE c = @aid;

        SET @RETURN_CODE = 0;
        SET @RETURN_MESSAGE = 'SUCCESS';
    END

    -- Log action and result in logging table for particular a_id
    -- also has id column as identity
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Logs] ([A_Id], [Created_Date], [Return_Code], [Return_Message])
    VALUES (@aid, GETDATE(), @RETURN_CODE, @RETURN_MESSAGE)

    SELECT @RETURN_CODE AS 'RETURN_CODE', @RETURN_MESSAGE AS 'RETURN_MESSAGE';
END
```

Comment: I'm guessing that you have obfuscated your code and your logic and, in doing so, removed all meaning. All we can do is guess. Your code does not handle errors **at all* and it eats real database errors by replacing them with a resultset. So start over. When an error occurs, you throw it; you don't return a resultset with "error" as the message. And stop defining everything as varchar(max). Lastly, your code always logs but does not always update. That seems odd. You will need to debug your procedure and how it is used more thoroughly.

Comment: Hi Thanks for suggestion. Actually the real procedure has try..catch, also the requirement is like I always has to log 'ID' is passed to procedure and is it available in the system or not thats why I always log the record but update only if t is available in the table.